# Count if the sum of a range meets a criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an approximately 54x15 array of dollar amounts that correspond to a month, year, and location. The locations correspond to districts (larger areas that encompass specific offices). I am attempting to create a table for each district counting the number of months that a certain dollar amount was met (how many months did a specific district have below $1M, between $1M and $2M, so on and so forth).

Because the locations and their dollar amounts correspond to districts, I can't quite figure out how to sum the dollar amounts under each location specifically for a larger district, and count the sums throughout the 54x15 array.

I think I could set aside the data and and sum each individually, but I am hoping there is a more efficient method. Attached below are pictures that will hopefully make my explanation make more sense.

Thank you for your help

[image: Data array with corresponding locations, months, and years. Locations correspond to larger encompassing districts, shown in the row above.]

[image: Table where the counts of how many months were in a certain range for each district are shown]

Comment: Sounds like you need a `countifs()` formula; are you able to change how your output works?  Different cell value for each of the dollar ranges might help more, e.g., row 1 has the min dollar value, row 2 has the max dollar value.

Comment: Very doable without merged headers. Also, the district total is the sum of the locations right? If multiple locations have between 1 and 2 mil a month, would that count or do you count the sum?

Comment: I apologize, I'm not exactly versed with excel so I don't quite understand. Even if I unmerged the headers, I would still want to count down each column, summing the rows only in the selected columns. I'm not sure how to write the countifs function to encompass the summation.

To better explain, I could count down the Capitol - Capitol column for whether they met the certain criteria, but I can't do anything with that because I also need to count down the Capitol - Southern Virginia column. The summation of those rows is what I want to be counting. I hope I am explaining this well enough

Comment: @piccolom5 merged columns make a match in a formula to count appropriate columns more difficult. My rule of thumb, just avoid merged cells in Excel in general :)

Comment: Yes it looks quite tricky even without the merged cells because as far as I can see you'd need an array formula to get the row totals within each area, so you couldn't use countifs with that but would need another array formula to count the ones that fell into each range 0-1 mil etc. I might be easier just to put in helper columns to total the offices within each district for each month.